# Share FormType between entities, best practice/approach

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have some entities that share the same structure, for example, take this two as a base example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="nomencladores.modelo", schema="nomencladores")
 */
class Modelo
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
    use NamedEntityTrait;
    use ActiveEntityTrait;

    /**
     * @var \TipoTramite
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TipoTramite")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipo_tramite_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $tipo_tramite;

    /**
     * Set tipo tramite
     *
     * @param  \ComunBundle\Entity\TipoTramite $tipo_tramite
     * @return FabricanteDistribuidor
     */
    public function setTipoTramite(\ComunBundle\Entity\TipoTramite $tipo_tramite)
    {
        $this->tipo_tramite = $tipo_tramite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tipo tramite
     *
     * @return \ComunBundle\Entity\TipoTramite
     */
    public function getTipoTramite()
    {
        return $this->tipo_tramite;
    }

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="nomencladores.marca", schema="nomencladores")
 */
class Marca
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;
    use NamedEntityTrait;
    use ActiveEntityTrait;

    /**
     * @var \TipoTramite
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TipoTramite")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipo_tramite_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $tipo_tramite;

    /**
     * Set tipo tramite
     *
     * @param  \ComunBundle\Entity\TipoTramite $tipo_tramite
     * @return FabricanteDistribuidor
     */
    public function setTipoTramite(\ComunBundle\Entity\TipoTramite $tipo_tramite)
    {
        $this->tipo_tramite = $tipo_tramite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tipo tramite
     *
     * @return \ComunBundle\Entity\TipoTramite
     */
    public function getTipoTramite()
    {
        return $this->tipo_tramite;
    }

}
```

As you can see in the code above the entities share almost the same code, just change the table where information is store. Now I need to build a form for each of them and basically will be the same with some minor changes, see this example for `Modelo` entity:

```
class ModeloType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('nombre')
                ->add('activo')
                ->add('tipo_tramite', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'ComunBundle:TipoTramite',
                    'property' => 'nombre',
                    'empty_value' => '-- SELECCIONAR --',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('qb')
                                ->where('qb.activo = :activoValue')
                                ->setParameter('activoValue', TRUE);
                    }
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ComunBundle\Entity\Modelo'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Modelo';
    }

}
```

So, the only things changing between one FormType and the other will be: the class name, the `data_class` attribute and the `getName()` return value, is there any way to apply DRY on FormType on this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, having two almost identical Entities (and hence two almost identical tables) seems like a smell to me - I'd think hard about somehow combining them into one Entity with some additional category to distinguish them.

That aside, can you just define your own intermediate abstract type, and then inherit from that changing those two small things that are different, e.g.

```
//This is not a good name, I'm sure you can do better!
abstract class AbstractModeloMarcaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('nombre')
                ->add('activo')
                ->add('tipo_tramite', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'ComunBundle:TipoTramite',
                    'property' => 'nombre',
                    'empty_value' => '-- SELECCIONAR --',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('qb')
                                ->where('qb.activo = :activoValue')
                                ->setParameter('activoValue', TRUE);
                    }
        ));
    }

    abstract protected function getDataClass();

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->getDataClass()
        ));
    }

}

public class ModeloType extends AbstractModeloMarcaType 
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Modelo';
    }

    public function getDataClass()
    {
        return 'ComunBundle\Entity\Modelo';
    }
}

public class MarcaType extends AbstractModeloMarcaType 
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Marca';
    }

    public function getDataClass()
    {
        return 'ComunBundle\Entity\Marca';
    }
}
```

Comment: the entities are almost identically but share relationship with different tables for that I leave the two, I'm not the expert behind the DB model, that's the DB Architect, I'm the guy behind the code